# how can I allow my user to copy files onto samba share without root (sudo)?

Tags: permissions, samba

I mounted a samba share on my system to a  mount point I made accessible to the world with `chmod 777` and `chown`-ed it to my user but as soon as I mount the share, the permissions change to `755` and the user switches to `root`. So how can I make the share writable to my user?

Comment: Please show us the relevant sections of your server config.

Comment: @lain I do not have access to the server, I'm only configuring the client for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The protocol deals with those permissions**

You need to setup those permissions when you mount the share. See the man page for `mount.cifs` or the link below.

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html

**Specifically take note of the following**

> **file_mode=arg** If the server does not support the CIFS Unix extensions
>   this overrides the default file mode.
>
> **dir_mode=arg** If the server does not support the CIFS Unix extensions
>   this overrides the default mode for directories.

There's also

> **uid=arg** sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the
>   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric
>   uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper
>   must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in
>   non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND
>   PERMISSIONS below for more information.
>
> **forceuid** instructs the client to ignore any uid provided by the server
>   for files and directories and to always assign the owner to be the
>   value of the uid= option. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY
>   OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS below for more information.
>
> **gid=arg** sets the gid that will own all files or directories on the
>   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information. It may be specified as either a groupname or a numeric
>   gid. When not specified, the default is gid 0. The mount.cifs helper
>   must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the gid in
>   non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND
>   PERMISSIONS below for more information.
>
> **forcegid** instructs the client to ignore any gid provided by the server
>   for files and directories and to always assign the owner to be the
>   value of the gid= option. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY
>   OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS below for more information.

**It sounds like you want something *similar* to this**

```
mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxx,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //server/share /mnt
```

**Or you can restrict it to a specific user with *something* like this**

```
mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxx,uid=1000,gid=1000 //server/share /mnt
```